# Why does my grammar check want to correct "versus" to "or"?

Tags: conjunctions

I typed the following sentence into Google Docs:

> The calculation becomes more involved, since there are several different ways to use the silicon wafers (polycrystalline versus monocrystalline).

The word *versus* was underlined in red, and right-clicking yielded

> Did you mean: **or**

What's going on here? Fwiw, it does the same thing if I use *vs* instead of *versus*.

Comment: "versus" comes up when you are comparing two things. In your case, you are talking about several different ways, and so using **or** allows you to state two possible ways out of all the possible ways to use the silicon wafers.

Comment: *several different ways*, as you can see, goes with the conjunction *and* (not *or*), not *versus* (which compares). Naturally?

Comment: If you mean 'The calculation becomes more involved, since there are several different ways to use the silicon wafers (some of which apply solely to the polycrystalline varieties and some solely to the monocrystalline),' I'd prefer this form. If you mean 'The calculation becomes more involved, since there are several different ways to use the silicon wafers (which come in two forms: polycrystalline and monocrystalline),' I would separate this into two sentences as the information is rather loosely connected.

Answer (score 5):

The software doesn't really understand the sentence, and is giving you bad advice. There is nothing wrong with *versus* here; you are indeed comparing two things.

> [versus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/versus?q=versus): as opposed to; in contrast to:

The fact that you're comparing them isn't stated explicitly in your sentence, but is presumably implicit from the context of the previous sentences; this may be why the grammar checker in Google Docs is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to convey a different idea, you should use "rather than." Otherwise get rid of that sentence and clarify what you mean by "versus" without using the word -- because as you can note from the discussion above, it is unclear what you mean, even if you are writing for specialists.

Comment: +1 for the alternative explanation. But notice that you're going _beyond_ what OP actually says, as do 'the discussers above', and pointing out that it needs clarification. And that I'm not accusing you of being _sincerely a mean person_ for doing so.

Comment: ;-)
I was playing, friend. But thank you for the +1. Thanks for the critique too.

Comment: Context is important. When one has corresponded with / read the correspondences of a person for a few months, one might be in a position to assess how that person might react to irony.

Answer (score 0):

"Vs" is used when you are comparing 2 things, in your case you seem to be stating 2 things but not trying to yield a comparison of some sort